# Content Security Policy default Setup of Primefaces restricts Bootsfaces scripts

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bootsfaces

[image]I've a project using Primefaces & Bootsfases, when I enabled, I encountered many issues in Ajax calls

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I've tried to customize the policy as described here https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/contentsecuritypolicy?id=content-security-policy

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP_POLICY</param-name>
    <param-value>script-src 'self' https:***cdn of blocked scripts*** </param-value>
</context-param>
```

But no effect, appreciate if anyone has any clue.

Comment: Errors in ajax calls by PF components or BF components?

Comment: Please post your exact CSP errors as well.

Comment: @Kukeltje in BF components

Comment: @Melloware, usually any ajax call from bootsfaces table, for example open Dialog for selected row, I'll post image for the errors

Comment: @Melloware, Image Added

Comment: Yep it looks like its using "Inline" scripts are a not allowed.  I think you are going to have to contact the BootsFaces developer and report this issue. The PF Datatable works fine.  see: https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues